# Show waiting notification till callback returns from thread

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, android-asynctask, android-activity

I am new to android and am stuck with this situation

I am calling a thread from the Activity UI. The thread will return to a callback function after doing some background operation .

Till then I need to show a waiting notification in the Activity UI.[Effectively freezing the app till the callback returns]

I tried with status flags and async task, but with partial success.

Please tell me the optimal solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show A Progress before you start a thread and dismiss the progress dialog just before returning.

For more about progress dialog see this link :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the progress dialog box just before you start your thread.

```
  private CustomizeDialog mCustomizeDialog = null;
  //in onCreate method
 mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v) {
   //checking few condition 
   mCustomizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(makeRequestActivity.this);
   mCustomizeDialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
   mCustomizeDialog.setMessage("Make Request?");
    mCustomizeDialog.okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                mCustomizeDialog.dismiss();
                                show();
     });
mCustomizeDialog.show();
   private void show() {
                                mCustomizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(makeRequestActivity.this);
                                mCustomizeDialog.setTitle("Requesting");
                                mCustomizeDialog.setMessage("Connecting...");
                                mCustomizeDialog.okButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mCustomizeDialog.cancelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                mCustomizeDialog.show();
                    }
```

and in my broadcast receiver

```
  private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction().equals(request.CUSTOM_INTENT_MENU)) {
            mExtras = intent.getExtras();
            String result = mExtras.getString("tag");
            if (mCustomizeDialog.isShowing()) {
                mCustomizeDialog.dismiss();
            }
           }
};
```